# NetworkManager[757]: <warn> [1461836136.9728] (wlan0): error getting signal strength: No such device

Tags: networking, 16.04, syslog

I get this error in the syslog and kern.log:
NetworkManager[757]:   [1461836136.9728] (wlan0): error getting signal strength: No such device

I have both an ethernet and wifi connection: Ethernet="Wired connection 1", Wifi="ABC"

New install of Ubuntu 16.04,any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Enabling the 300MBit limit in my Router helped for me.

My NetGear WNA3100 is barely running on my Ubuntu 16.04. Often I have to disable/re-enable my Network and wireless Network to get a working connection. The download speed is a horrible 0.25MB/sec., 10% of normal speed. A NetGear WNDA3100v2 is totally not going to work.

However its running for now. A more Linux conpatible WLan-Stick will be my next investment.

Answer (score 0):

Newer kernels label network adapters differently because there were confusions many times. Now the network adapters are labeled uniquely. That means that if you replace the network adapter it will not be labeled as the previous (eth0, wlan0, etc.). However, NetworkManager still uses wlan0 label.

You can find the description of the bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1594814

The workarounds described in the presented bug report are:

1. Restart NetworkManager with `sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service`
2. In file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` under [main] change:

   dhcp=dhclient

   to

   dhcp=internal

It also says that the bug was fixed on 2016-07-08. So I am awaiting an update, which will fix it.